# Why must an Angular component clone an object returned by a service?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-httpclient

I'm going through the HttpClient page in the [Angular Fundamentals](https://angular.io/guide/http) section, and I was wondering why the component must **clone** the object received from the service that makes the HTTP calls?

The specific `config.component.ts` code block on the page (in [this section](https://angular.io/guide/http#type-checking-the-response)) that I'm talking about is this one:

```
config: Config;

showConfig() {
  this.configService.getConfig()
    // clone the data object, using its known Config shape
    .subscribe(data => this.config = { ...data });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because otherwise you would breach so called "data encapsulation" concept and your app might behave very weird. Service.ts class is a singleton (as usual) and all components that injects it, shares the same instance of it.

So in all those components, `this.configService.getConfig().subscribe(data =>` , `data` object is a one object. And if components doesn't clone it, just assigns its reference, and later someone mutates that `data`, some weirdness would begin because in component `this.config` is considered as a static object (after subscription completes) and if you don't clone it, it would reference to the `data` from your service which is a dynamic object.

And in general, Javascript assigns objects by reference, so its always safer to clone things and keep data separate and mutate things in one place - so called, data store. Angular service.ts is an equivalent to the data store.

*Thats how I would explain it. Would love to see more answers.*